# How make a leaderboard with JSON database in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, discord.js

I would like to create a leaderboard to make it in my discord bot.

Already to start it, I made a JSON classic database with just `userID` and `Coins` columns.

```js
{"3879720334874588161":{"coins":5},"3919222756303420417":{"coins":5}}
```

Now I would make a leaderboard with this database, but I have some problem:

```
(node:15500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: coins.sort is not a function
    at Object.module.exports.run (c:\Users\StarKleey\Desktop\Bot discord\Bot Folletto\Commandes\list.js:9:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
warning.js:32
(node:15500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
warning.js:32
(node:15500) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

And my code is as follows

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  await message.delete();

  let coins = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./coins.json", "utf8"));

  coins.sort([
    ['coins', 'descending']
  ]).exec((err, res) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Coins Leaderboard")
    //if there are no results
    if (res.length === 0) {
      embed.setColor("RED");
      embed.addField("No data found", "Please type in chat to gain coins!")
    } else if (res.length < 10) {
      //less than 10 results
      embed.setColor("BLURPLE");
      for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        let member = message.guild.members.get(res[i].userID) || "User Left"
        if (member === "User Left") {
          embed.addField(`${i + 1}. ${member}`, `**Coins**: ${res[i].coins}`);
        } else {
          embed.addField(`${i + 1}. ${member.user.username}`, `**Coins**: ${res[i].coins}`);
        }
      }
    } else {
      //more than 10 results
      embed.setColor("BLURPLE");
      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let member = message.guild.members.get(res[i].userID) || "User Left"
        if (member === "User Left") {
          embed.addField(`${i + 1}. ${member}`, `**Coins**: ${res[i].coins}`);
        } else {
          embed.addField(`${i + 1}. ${member.user.username}`, `**Coins**: ${res[i].coins}`);
        }
      }
    }

    message.channel.send(embed);
  })
}
module.exports.help = {
  name: "leaders"
}
```

Could someone solve my problem or know another solution to do a leaderboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have says that `coins.sort() is not a function`.

Your coins variable is an Object. If you look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) / another website for what methods are available on an object, you will see that there is no sort method available.

So you are trying to call a function that does not exist, hence the error.

### Current way you are storing users & coins (not recommended)

If you want to sort your coins object with your current file you could use

```js
const sorted = [];
const keys = Object.keys(coins)

for (let user in coins) {
  const coin = coins[user].coins;
  
  const entry = {[keys[sorted.length]] : coins[user]}
  
  if (sorted.length === 0) {
    sorted.push(entry);

    continue;
  }
  let i = 0;
  while (sorted[i] !== undefined && sorted[i][Object.keys(sorted[i])].coins > coin) {
    i++;
  }
    
  sorted.splice(i, 0, entry)
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Twiggeh99/5rxa9bLo/36/)

### The way I would store the users and then sort (recommended)

I would recommend to save your users with coins as :

```js
[{userID: "123", coins: 12}, ]
```

then you could use

```js
betterCoins.sort((a,b)=>{b.coins - a.coins});
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Twiggeh99/5rxa9bLo/37/)

You can also just cast your Object to an array and use the recommended method without needing to change how your file is structured :

```js
const newCoins = [];

for(let userObj in coins){
    newCoins.push({"name" : userObj, "coins": coins[userObj].coins })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm going to do it your way right away !

Comment: Hey, I'm back to ask you if you have a tutorial or documentation to explain your solutions to me

Comment: @StarKleey I am not sure which part(s) of my solution(s) you don't understand, if you can provide more context I might be able to help.

Comment: I don't understand how u save your data ? it's on json or directly on js ? And i don't know how i can my data like you.